Is it necessary to call load() before compare_exchange_strong()？
I was learning about C++ memory sequence, and I found this code in Unreal Engine5. My question is why not call compare_exchange_strong() directly instead of load() first?
FHttpRequest* GetFreeRequest()
{
    for (uint8 i = 0; i < Pool.Num(); ++i)
    {
    if (!Pool[i].Usage.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) //<-why load first?
    {
        uint8 Expected = 0u;
        if (Pool[i].Usage.compare_exchange_strong(Expected, 1u))
        {
            Pool[i].Request->Reset();
            return Pool[i].Request;
        }
    }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

I think it's okay to remove the load() call and change it to something like this:
FHttpRequest* GetFreeRequest()
{
    for (uint8 i = 0; i < Pool.Num(); ++i)
    {
    uint8 Expected = 0u;
        if (Pool[i].Usage.compare_exchange_strong(Expected, 1u))
    {
            Pool[i].Request->Reset();
        return Pool[i].Request;
    }
    }
    return nullptr;
}



why load first?

Because .load(std::memory_order_relaxed) (read) is fast and .compare_exchange_strong(Expected, 1u) (read-modify-write) is slow.
This is slow once, and then fast until Usage is reset.
if (!Pool[i].Usage.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
    // ...
    if (Pool[i].Usage.compare_exchange_strong(Expected, 1u))

This is slow always
if (Pool[i].Usage.compare_exchange_strong(Expected, 1u))


Both ways are correct, the difference is performance.
For a simple spinlock (or mutex with fallback to .wait / .notify_one()), load first is often worse.  Making the first access to a cache line a pure load can end up with the cache line in MESI Shared state if it was hot in another core's cache.  In that case the RMW (CAS) has to do another off-core access (Read For Ownership, RFO) to get MESI Exclusive ownership of the cache line to modify it.
Related: Does cmpxchg write destination cache line on failure? If not, is it better than xchg for spinlock? / Locks around memory manipulation via inline assembly (the section on first access to the cache line).
But this isn't just one lock where we spin or sleep if it's not available, it's scanning an array for a free entry.  So there's still useful work to do if we find Pool[i] isn't available: move on to the next entry and check it.
It's very good to have fast scanning with good memory-level and instruction-level parallelism until we find an available entry we can try to claim.  A pure load, especially a relaxed load on non-x86 ISAs, gives us that.  A CAS attempt wouldn't especially on x86 where lock cmpxchg is always a full RMW even if the compare fails, and is a full memory barrier that wouldn't allow any overlap of loads.  (I'm not sure how ARMv8.1 single-instruction atomic RMWs perform; without it, ldrex / compare+branch / strex (LL/SC) can early-out without trying to store, but it still asks for exclusive ownership of the cache line.)

uint8 i seems like a poor choice.  Some compilers might fail to optimize away truncation and zero-extension to pointer width, spending a few extra instructions every iteration.  They should use at least int or unsigned.  Types narrower than int sometimes take extra work.
Narrow types are great for arrays; loading with sign or zero extension is normally free, and save cache footprint.  But for locals like loop counters, they're still going to get a whole register to themselves.
